# Is there a way to get the decorated class name from inside an attribute?

Tags: reflection, attributes, system.reflection

So, I have perhaps a strange case that I need to solve this way.

```
[MyAttribute]
public class SomeUser
{

}
```

The challenge here is, I need to get the name of the decorated class ('SomeUser') inside the code of `MyAttribute`

Is there a way to do this? Like this example code:

```
public class MyAttributeAttribute: Attribute
{
    public MyAttributeAttribute()
    {

       //I'M LOOKING FOR SOMETHING LIKE THIS
       //var decoratedClass = this.GetType().GetDecoratedClass().Name;

    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I need to identify the class name within the attribute, I know how to do this from outside, like "give me the classes with the attribute" but this case will not work for me.

Thanks